# Why server app receives 50% of client messages?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

Pre:

Client open socket to send data to the server:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    client = new TcpClient();
    client.BeginConnect("127.0.0.1", 995, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
}

private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult _result) // it will send hello message from client
{
    string data;
    byte[] remdata = { };
    IAsyncResult inResult = _result;

    currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    string currentProcessAsText = currentProcess.Id.ToString();

    SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(proccessIdLabel, "Text", currentProcessAsText);

    try {
        sock = client.Client;

        // send hello message
        data = "Client with proccess id " + currentProcessAsText + " is connecting";
        sock.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data));
        SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(answersTextBox, "Text", answersTextBox.Text + "\n"+ GetCurrentTime() + " Connection established");
    }
    catch
    {
        SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(answersTextBox, "Text", answersTextBox.Text + "\n" + GetCurrentTime() + " Can't connect");
    }
}
```

After that I have handler for click on some button (to send messages):

```
private void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string data;
        sock = client.Client;
        data = "Some text";
        sock.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data));
    }
    catch
    {
        SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(answersTextBox, "Text", "Can't connect");
    }
}
```

Also handler for form close to send server `exit` command, so he will stop thread for this client:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        sock.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("exit"));
        sock.Close();
    }            
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Server listening port and handles messages:

```
private void Listeners()
{
    Socket socketForClient = Listener.AcceptSocket();
    string data;

    int i = 0;

    if (socketForClient.Connected)
    {
        string remoteHost = socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(Message("Client:" + remoteHost + " now connected to server."));

        while (true)
        {
                // буфер данных
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            try
            {
                int messageLength = socketForClient.Receive(buf);
                if (messageLength > 0)
                {
                    byte[] cldata = new byte[messageLength];
                    socketForClient.Receive(cldata);
                    data = "";
                    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(cldata).Trim();
                    if (data.Contains("exit"))
                    {
                        socketForClient.Close();
                        string message = Message("Client:" + remoteHost + " is disconnected from the server (client wish).");
                        Console.WriteLine(message);
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(Message("Recevied message from client " + remoteHost + ":\n"));
                        Console.WriteLine(data);
                        Console.WriteLine("\nEOF\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                string message = Message("Client:" + remoteHost + " is disconnected from the server (forced close).");
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                socketForClient.Close();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
private void ServStart()
{
    Listener = new TcpListener(LocalPort);
    Listener.Start(); // начали слушать
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting connections [" + Convert.ToString(LocalPort) + "]...");

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listeners));
        newThread.Start();
    }
}
```

So on server start it creates 1000 threads, which are listens clients messages.

Problems:

I will describe some situation:

1. Start server

Server starts threads and ready to accept clients connections

2. Start client

Connection is establishing. Server says that client connected on some port. Client send "hello" message. Server *doesn't handle* this hello message.

3. Push the button, so client will send Some text to the server. Server *handles* this message.
4. Push the button. Client sends "some text" again. Server *doesn't handles* that message.
5. Push the button. Client sends "some text" again. Server *handles* that message.
6. If I will push again, it will not handle it obviously....

Server logs:

[image]

Why server receives/client sends only 1 of 2 messages? What can cause it?

Also I have problems with sending `exit` message to the server, when client form is closing. I send `exit` message on this action.

So situation:

1. I just pushed the button and *server handled it* (so server will not handle next message).
2. I close the form, message is sended, but either client sends wrong message or server receives wrong message.

Situation in console:

[image]

You can see, that when form was closed and client sended `exit`, server handled `empty` message. Why?

Situation when client `exit` command passed by server normally:

1. .....
2. Client sends data, server doesn't handled it
3. Now, server will handle client, so we try to close form:

Console:

[image]

So in 2nd item client had sended hello message and server failed to handle it. In 3rd item client sends exit command and server passed it correctly.

Main question: why server handles only 1 of 2 messages from client?

Another point: also I found, that when client send `exit` data, server receives `exit\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\` (or more, or less `\0` symbols). Why?

Good news I think, that server receives or not receives messages constantly. 1 message is received, 1 message is not. That says about my lack of knowledges, but not random error.

Comment: Did you ever find out why you were receiving "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\"? I am having this issue right now but only on 1 client (which leads me to believe it is something strange with the hardware setup).

Comment: Mhm. First way was to trim `\0` in server side. Second way - I changed approach to send and receive messages I think... But I can miss something. I don't remember much sry

Comment: No problem, thanks anyway. For now I am doing the same anyway (telling the server to ignore the '\0')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So many bugs. :(

That said, the biggest one I noticed was this one:

```
int messageLength = socketForClient.Receive(buf);
if (messageLength > 0)
{
    byte[] cldata = new byte[messageLength];
    socketForClient.Receive(cldata);
    data = "";
    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(cldata).Trim();
```

First, understand that in TCP, you have no guarantees about the number of bytes any given receive operation will receive. No matter how the remote endpoint sends the data, you could receive all of the data at once, or only parts of it, in separate receive operations. TCP guarantees the bytes will be received in the same *order* in which they were sent, and nothing more.

But the above code not only fails to take that into account, it's just completely wrong. The number of bytes received in the first operation is how many bytes were received *in that operation*. But you are using that number as if it would tell you something about the number of bytes received in the *next* call to `Receive()`. It does nothing of the sort. At the same time, you ignore the data you received in the first operation.

Instead, your code should look more like this:

```
int messageLength = socketForClient.Receive(buf);
if (messageLength > 0)
{
    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, messageLength).Trim();
```

That's still not quite right, because of course you could receive just a partial message in the call to `Receive()`, or even more than one message concatenated together. But at least you're likely to see all of the text.

That change will address the specific question you've asked about.